# rewrite urls in CouchDB

Tags: mod-rewrite, couchdb

How do I rewrite URLs in CouchDB to be more friendly?  Mod_rewrite may be all I need, but I don't have a clue how to implement it on CouchDB without Apache. I really want to stay away from anything that won't replicate to another Couch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

mod_rewrite is **Apache**'s rewrite module. You won't be using it if you don't have an Apache installed.

There's some [rudimentary URL rewriting](http://blog.couchbase.com/what%E2%80%99s-new-apache-couchdb-011-%E2%80%94-part-one-nice-urls-rewrite-rules-and-virtual-hosts) available in CouchDB 0.11 and up. Nothing groundbreaking, but it might do the job.

If everything else fails, you can always set up a proxy in front of your CouchDB instances. This way, replication happens using the standard URLs, but external users can use the clean URLs rewritten by the Apache proxy's mod_rewrite.

Comment: Fixed. The couchbase blog screwed up their URL rewriting when they changed blog platforms, but the articles are still there.